# php- get last insert id

Tags: php, mysql

I know this question has been answered many times. I tried a few of the solutions from here but nothing worked. I'm not using any PHP framework.

I have an insert operation taking place and I want to get the id of the inserted row.

Here's my code:

```
$qry="INSERT INTO tablename(content) VALUES('".$content."')";
setData($qry);
```

setData() is a user defined function which does insert operation.

```
//for data submit
function setData($qry)
{
    $obj=new DBCon();
    $res=$obj->submitQuery($qry);
    return $res;
}

//fetches result
function getData($qry)
{
    $obj=new DBCon();
    $res=$obj->selectQuery($qry);
    return $res;
}
```

This is the class I made for establishing database connectivity:

```
class DBCon
    {   
        private function getConnection()
        {   
                               // hostname,   username,     password,   database
            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname")OR die('Could not Connect the Database');        
            return $con;
        }

        public function closeCon()
        {
            mysqli_close($con);
        }

        public function submitQuery($qry)
        {
            $result=0;
            $con=$this->getConnection();
            $result=mysqli_query($con,$qry);
            return $result;
        }

        public function selectQuery($qry)
        {
            $con=$this->getConnection();
            $res=mysqli_query($con,$qry);
            return $res;
        }
    }
```

To obtain the last inserted id, I wrote the following query but it did not yield any result:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM tablename
```

Is there any other method to get this?

Comment: Try this $id  = last_insert_id(); after your insert query

Comment: maybe interesting? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php i.e. `$lastId = mysqli_insert_id ($connection);`

Comment: You haven't really shared any of your attempts so it's impossible to say what you're doing wrong or why you thought you had to run `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM tablename` manually. We can only speculate and my guess it that you don't fetch the ID right after the insertion and in the same connection.

Answer (score 5):

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` only returns values that have been auto-generated by the MySQL server for an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column; when you insert a specific value, no auto-generation takes place and no value will be returned by `LAST_INSERT_ID().`

Try : `$con->insert_id;`

Comment: this does not produce any result @Mohammad Fareed

Comment: is your table has id related column with auto_increment primary key .?

Comment: @Amelia Earheart any result now.?

Comment: Yes auto increment field is there. @Mohammad Fareed

Comment: try $conn->insert_id;

Comment: db::getInstance()->lastInsertId();

Answer (score 1):

Try This way.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('First Name', 'Last Name', 'first@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: The problem with vague questions is that there's no way to say whether a usage example (which the OP purportedly tried and didn't like) solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

MySQLi Object-oriented

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

MySQLi Procedural

```
     <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

PDO

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDBPDO";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
    VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    $last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
```

Comment: You should explain what your code does.. a code only answer is generally flagged as low quality at SO