# PHP/Oracle - Insert in the pk column

Tags: php, oracle, zend-framework

Is it possible in PHP to ask to insert in the PK column a value which is incremented compared to its last saved value?

Myphp

```
public function insertNewClient($idDeposant)
{
    $data = array(
        'RAI_SOC'           => 'A compléter de toute urgence',
        'CODE_CLIENT'       => 'XXXXX',
        'STATUT_CLI'        => '2',
        'COND_REGL'         => '2',
        'CODE_COCLICO'      => $idDeposant    
    );

    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        if($value === null)
            unset($data[$key]);
    }
    $this->getDbTable()->insert($data);
}
```

How i execute this function :

```
        $idDeposant = (int)$data->IdentificationDepot['IDDeposant'];
        $client = new Application_Model_Client();
        $clientMapper = new Application_Model_ClientMapper();
        $clientMapper->getClientByCodeCoclico($idDeposant, $client);
        $idClient = $client->getClientID();            

        // Jira 407
        // Si le client n'existe pas, on crée un nouveau client 
        if ($idClient == NULL)
        {
        $idDeposant = (int)$data->IdentificationDepot['IDDeposant'];
        $client = new Application_Model_Client();
        $clientMapper = new Application_Model_ClientMapper();
        $clientMapper->insertNewClient($idDeposant);
        $idClient = $client->getClientID();
        }
```

when I insert a new client in my table with the insertNewClient function, I would like to assign a client_id automatically and then take it back in my php code to manipulate the value.

Comment: Why you want to do that in PHP and not in the SQL? and what the connection to the error message you posted?

Comment: hello @dWinder, thanks for answer. I need to do this in php because a user will execute this function everytime a var is empty in a xml file. I agree with you, the error message does not help a lot, i will delete it.

Comment: Have a look at this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37832420/php-get-last-insert-id